find a contour integral using the residue theorem
So I need to find this contour integral
$\int_C (z^2e^{\frac{1}{\pi z}} + \frac{ze^z}{z^4-\pi ^4})$, with $C: 4x^2 + y^2 = 16$.
I think I'd have something like
$\int_C (z^2e^{\frac{1}{\pi z}} + \frac{ze^z}{z^4-\pi ^4}) = 2\pi i [Res(f, -\pi i) + Res(f, \pi i)]$,
( $f(z):= (z^2e^{\frac{1}{\pi z}} + \frac{ze^z}{z^4-\pi ^4})$ )
by using the Residue Theorem and the fact that the only zeros of the function in question are $\pi$, $-\pi$, $-\pi i$ and $\pi i$, but with only the 2 latter values being inside of C.
Now, can I state that f has a pole of order n on those points?

There are indeed poles of order $1$ at $-\pi i$ and $+\pi i$.  There is also an isolated singularity at $z = 0$, coming from the $e^{1/(\pi z)}$.

Let's rename the functions
$$
f(z) = z^2e^{1/\pi z} \quad\&\quad g(z) = \frac{ze^z}{z^4-\pi^4}
$$
for convenience.
$g(z)$ possesses four poles at $\pm\pi$ and $\pm i\pi$, because its denominator can be factorized into $z^4-\pi^4 = (z^2-\pi^2)(z^2+\pi^2) = (z-\pi)(z+\pi)(z-i\pi)(z+i\pi)$, but only the last two lie inside the ellipse $C : 4x^2 + y^2 = 16$, since $\pi^2 < 16 < 4\pi^2$. You can check that they are indeed poles of order 1, since the limits
$$
\lim_{z\to\pm i\pi} (z-(\pm i\pi))g(z) = \lim_{z\to\pm i\pi} \frac{ze^z}{(z^2-\pi^2)(z\pm i\pi)} = \frac{1}{4\pi^3}
$$
exist. Moreover, they coincide to the associated residues.
However, $f(z)$ displays an essential singularity at $z = 0$ too $-$ that is an infinite-order pole, if you prefer $-$, whose residue has to be determined from its series expansion, namely
$$
f(z) = z^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\pi z)^{-n}}{n!} = z^2 + \frac{z}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2\pi^2} + \frac{1}{6\pi^3z} + \frac{1}{24\pi^4z^2} + \ldots
$$
hence $\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) = \frac{1}{6\pi^3}$.
In consequence, one has at the end :
$$
\oint_C f(z) + g(z) \,\mathrm{d}z 
   = 2\pi i \left(\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) + \operatorname{Res}(g(z),i\pi) + \operatorname{Res}(g(z),-i\pi)\right) 
   = \frac{4}{3}\frac{i}{\pi^2}
$$
